# Sharepoint 2013: How do I set a different/change term for all existing files in a document library from the term store?

Tags: sharepoint, tags, metadata, sharepoint-2013, document-library

I am using Managed metadata for a specific column in a document library in in Sharepoint 2013.

The term selected for this column (column name: *committee*) has been set to *xxx* from the term store but it should be *yyy* (also from the term store).
I can set a different default term when I edit the (managed metadata) column (for instance *yyy*). If I then create a new folder or file it gets correctly tagged with *yyy* under the column *committee*.

**How do I change/update the tag for all of the existing folders and files to the new default value *xxx* within this specific document library?**

I need to do it in sharepoint for this document library only as both of the tems are used correctly in other document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way will be using the quick edit. You can directly change the managed metadata column value for all items with the fill handle.

[image]

Or you can use a PowerShell script to update all the files in the library.

Here a script I test. It works in my end.

```
#Variables
$WebURL="http://sp/"
$ListName="Documents"
$FieldName="TF"
 
#Get the web
$Web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL    
 
#Get the Term from Term store
$TaxonomySession = Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site $web.Site
$TermStore = $TaxonomySession.TermStores[0]
$TermGroup = $TermStore.Groups["Test Term Set Group"]
$TermSet = $TermGroup.TermSets["Task force"]
$Term = $Termset.Terms["Beta"]
 

#Get the List and List Item
$List= $Web.Lists[$listName]
$Items = $List.items
 
Foreach ( $item in $items)
{
#set managed metadata field value powershell
$MMSField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$Item.Fields[$FieldName]
$MMSField.setFieldValue($Item,$Term)
$Item.Update()
 }
```

Reference: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2015/12/read-update-managed-metadata-column-values-using-powershell.html